# Pull row count from action query

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a form button that runs a delete query and an append query.  I would like to be able to show the user how many rows will be deleted and how many will be appended and store them on the form.  The queries already exist outside the VBA for the button.  So I am just calling the queries with DoCmd.OpenQuery.  I turned off the warnings so the popup doesn't happen that says "Do you really want to delete this many rows?"  But I would still like to find out how many rows will be deleted or appended and store that number as a variable somewhere so the user can see it.  How can I make that happen?

I tried a DCount function but because these are action queries it won't work.  I would also like to avoid putting the SQL for the queries in my VBA.  I like that they are separate from the VBA and can be edited on their own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming ACE / Jet, you can use an instance of currentdb to run the queries and then look at the RecordsAffected property.

```
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb

db.Execute "Delete From Table1 Where Id = 1"
Debug.Print db.RecordsAffected
```

Or with a saved query

```
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb

db.Execute "ADelete"
Debug.Print db.RecordsAffected
```

Comment: I haven't done that before.  What is the basic VBA to do that?

Comment: This worked.  Thank you.  I had to edit my queries a bit to get it to work.  It kept telling me there were too few parameters because I had one of the criteria set by what the user entered into the form.  I guess I need to learn more about the .execute function.  Normally I use OpenQuery.  But OpenQuery can't tell me the records affected.  Thank again for your help.  It works perfectly.

Comment: If you need user input, consider parameters and an instance of the query ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525583/run-update-query-within-vba-code/12528868#12528868 ) a querydef also has records affected (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192040(v=office.15).aspx )